# Is is possible in jquery to submit a form and load another related page with a related form?

Tags: jquery, forms, overlay, chained

So, I have 4 pages in asp.

The first one gets the data from a user and saves it in a session variable.

The second one is used to upload a picture.

The third one is used to crop that picture (and save the cropped image).

The fourth is a confirm page and saves the data into a database.

Is it possible to "chain" all those forms from different pages using jquery? Do you know any tutorial on how to do that?

All I found in the web is to submit a form and then open a response message. I want to load the other form in the page, without the page refresh, or maybe do it all inside an overlay.

Thanks.

Comment: you probably need to learn more about AJAX, the `response message` you are talking about can be actually the next form! once you get going with AJAX, you can use something like [address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) to add a facebook/twitter -like page navigation

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to push the information gathered in the form and then pull the next form.

**Edit:** Here i found something better [jQuery Form Wizard](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/formwizard)

Hope it helps.